# schtasks in Windows how to select first day of month

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have the syntax how to define a Task for the last day of the month, but not fir the first day. Are there any Admin Gurus?

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo LASTDAY /tn "Bild Copy" /tr "C:\copy.bat"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command creates a scheduled task which runs the first day of every month. The default day is the first one, and the default month is every month, so you don't need to use additional parameters.

```
schtasks /create /tn "Bild Copy" /tr "C:\copy.bat" /sc monthly
```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: Thanks and, is it possible as well to define the time? in this mode, say at 06.00 am?

Comment: @user1767754 Yes, you need to use the `/st` parameter, e.g. `/st 06:00`. Make sure to check the [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx) which explains every single parameter available. There are plenty of examples available, too.